# How does a tablet or phone know when to initiate USB-C Power Delivery (PD) power role swap

Tags: usb, usb-c, usb-pd

I'm designing an interface that goes between what is essentially a basic USB-A "Device" (UFP) and a USB-C equipped user device.  The connection with the USB-C port could be either a laptop or tablet.  It is assumed that both the laptop and tablet would support USB-C PD (Power Delivery).  My problem is with power delivery direction control. The laptop is likely to (almost) always present itself as a UFP and source power to the USB-A device.  This part is fine and easy to deal with.  However, if the user swaps the laptop out for a tablet, they want the tablet to be charged while also communicating with the USB-A device as a host.  So, I need to be able to do power role swap, which is not a big deal either but my problem is that I don't know what initiates the swap, assuming the tablet will always likely come up in a sourcing role.  I have poured over the internet for many days and dug through the USB-C PD specs and cannot find an answer.  All I can find is that in PD compliant equipment/devices, power role swap is possible and either side can initiate.  That's it, no protocol or standard practices are offered.  In my case and in the functional scenarios for my product, I can never initiate it so I need the tablet to be able to do it.  But how?  Do tablets commonly have configuration settings for this or are there usually pop-ups presented to the user upon connection to select the option for sinking instead of sourcing power?

Below is a block of what I'm trying to do.  I plan to configure the PD controller as a UFP only.
When a laptop/PC is connected, it will come up as a DFP and the top switch in the diagram will close for 5V to reach the USB 2.0 (USB-A) device, no problem.  If the laptop is replaced with a tablet, it will also come up as a DFP but then we need a power role swap so the tablet can charge.   When that happens, the two switches toward the bottom would be closed instead.  The PD controller can detect the role swap request/command from the tablet but what makes the tablet initiate it?

Thanks for any insight.

[image]

Comment: My tablets never ask if they are going to source or sink power. At least, not me as the user, but on a system level somewhere... not sure never gone into the logs deep enough even if it gets logged.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Solar Mike.  I'm still stuck on this so if anyone else has thoughts, I'd appreciate it.